# Wordpress QNS Booking and PayU Payment gateway integration

Tags: php, wordpress, payu, payumoney

I have a wordpress plugin called QNS booking system in which there is only 2 payment methods 1) Paypal 2) Direct Bank Transaction but I like to add another transaction namely PayU which is very popular in India. I am not much into php but my client needs it. So I have added some coding which you can help me through to get an idea and what are the ways which this requirement can be achieved.
Note: payu is available for woo commerce but not for booking systems

> [PayU Woocommerce Integration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-payu-paisa/)
>
> [QNS Booking Plugin](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wjxlb9k20qb8o81/quitenicebooking.zip?dl=0)

I just need only the PayU Payment Gateway others can be optional
Please review the codings and give me a solution guys
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

To
integrate Payumoney in woocommerce "PayU" provides a simple plugin to
integrate. Install it, enter your credential and that’s all.. Done..

If you want to integrate it in wordpress non e-commerce site, it needs customization. Install PHP kit provided by payumoney.

The
most important you have to pass the values of all required parameter as
mentioned in their documentation. Pass these values with $_POST. That’s
it.

I have done the same thing in Hotel Booking system. Its working fine.If you need any further help, contact me on [aryamaae.com](http://aryamaae.com)